# Reference to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is ambiguous, both batchUpdate(String,Map<String,?>[]) and batchUpdate(String,SqlParameterSource[]) match

Tags: java, generics, methods, ambiguity

Maybe I'm missing something.  I get the following error when I try to compile code that is essentially the following:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL,
     values.stream().map(val->new MapBuilder<String,Object>()
                            .put("param1",val.getSomeProperty())
                            .put("param2",val.getSomeOtherProperty())
                            .build())
                    .toArray(Map[]::new);
```

Somehow this is ambiguous between batchUpdate(String,Map[]) and batchUpdate(String,SqlParameterSource[]).

SqlParamterSource does not implement Map. So where is the confusion?  Even IntelliJ's incremental compiler doesn't seem to have a problem with the code.  It's only when I attempt to compile the code from maven, or to run the code that it flags it as an error.

I can work around the issue by changing the code as follows:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL,
     values.stream().map(val->new MapBuilder<String,Object>()
                            .put("param1",val.getSomeProperty())
                            .put("param2",val.getSomeOtherProperty())
                            .build())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .toArray(new Map[0]);
```

I've tried searching for an answer, but all of the hits just explain scenarios where the ambiguity is already clear (to me).  This scenario however is puzzling to me.

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I will try to create a concise one.  The code I'm working on is proprietary, so I don't have permission to post it.

Answer (score 1):

### Not exactly an answer

After some investigation, the compile error is due to :

1. Overloading of method.
2. Calling overloading method where parameter is passed **directly** from generic method where the return type is inferred by a **Lambda Expression** or **Double Column Operator**.

However the reason (related JLS) is not found yet. Hope someone can give more explanation.

### Demonstration of the problem

The following code snippet demonstrates the above founding. The code is tested with jdk 1.8.0_151. Interestingly eclipse does not give compile error.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class AmbitguousMethodTest {
    private <A> A inferByFunctionalInterface(IntFunction<A> d) {
        return null;
    }

    private <A> A inferByArray(A[] a) {
        return null;
    }

    private <A> A inferByOutside() {
        return null;
    }

    private <A> A inferByList(List<A> d) {
        return null;
    }

    private void overloadMethod(BigDecimal a) {
    }

    private void overloadMethod(Integer a) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmbitguousMethodTest test = new AmbitguousMethodTest();
        testOverloading(test);
    }

    private static void testOverloading(AmbitguousMethodTest test) {
        // Compilation failure reference to overloadMethod is ambiguous
        // By double colon operator
        test.overloadMethod(test.inferByFunctionalInterface(BigDecimal::new));
        // By Lambda expression
        test.overloadMethod(test.inferByFunctionalInterface(i->new BigDecimal(i)));

        // Compile
        // By explicit functional interface
        test.overloadMethod(test.inferByFunctionalInterface(new IntFunction<BigDecimal>() {
            @Override
            public BigDecimal apply(int value) {
                return new BigDecimal(1);
            }
        }));
        test.overloadMethod(test.inferByArray(new BigDecimal[0]));
        test.overloadMethod(test.<BigDecimal>inferByOutside());
        test.overloadMethod(test.inferByList(new ArrayList<BigDecimal>()));
    }
}
```